# Работа кода на CodeWars

Tags: ruby, словарь

**CodeWars** выдает ошибку, а у меня на компьютере все отлично работает.

Скриншот с **CodeWars**
[image]

Код с компьютера:

```
def pick_peaks(arr)
    pos = []
    peaks = []
    for i in 1..arr.size-2
        if (arr[i] >= arr[i+1] && arr[1] > arr[i-1])
            pos << i
            peaks << arr[i]
        end
    end
    "{\"pos\"=>" + pos.to_s + ", \"peaks\"=>" + peaks.to_s + "}"
end
puts pick_peaks [3,2,3,6,4,1,2,3,2,1,2,3]
```

Как я понимаю для отображения `"` нужно поставить `\` перед `"`. Удивило то что на компьютере хорошо, но на сайте тупит. Может у кого-то было  такое? Прошу помочь в решении.

Comment: За скриншоты вместо кода нужно бить по пальцам :) Скриншоты хороши для дополнительный инфы, а не основной. Так что, пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос через кнопку `править` ваш код и текст ошибки

Comment: Да и нехватает в вопросе ссылки на задание. Это было бы логично для данной задачи :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по вашему коду, ошибке и коду в тестах:

- Вы возвращает строку
- А нужно вернуть объект

Не:

```
"{\"pos\"=>" + pos.to_s + ", \"peaks\"=>" + peaks.to_s + "}"
```

А:

```
{"pos" => pos, "peaks" => peaks}
```

Comment: большое спасибо